# How to merge two arraycollection and without duplicates?

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4

I want merge 2 array collection, where no duplicates are allowed,

```
var ac1:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([ {s:"4",e:"8"}, {s:"9",e:"10"}, ]);
var ac2:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([ {s:"2",e:"3"}, {s:"4",e:"8"}, {s:"9",e:"10"}, {s:"11",e:"12"}, ]);
```

how can I do it in efficient way

Thanks,

Comment: It's not such a difficult problem. What did you try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this is a good starter.

```
function equals(o1:Object, o2:Object)
{
    return (o1 && o2) && (o1 != o2) && (o1.s != o2.s) && (o1.e != o2.e);
}

function merge(a:Array, b:Array):Array
{
    const source = [];
    var isContained:Boolean = false;
    for (var i:int; i< a.length;i++) {
        isContained = false
        for (var j:int; j< b.length;j++) {
            if (equals(a[i], b[j])) {
                isContained = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!isContained) {
            source.push(a[1]);
        }
    }
    return source.concat(b);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, what if I have 10 properties in object(Eg, s, e, name, destin... etc), do I need to compare all properties!

Answer (score 1):

Errr, I'm not an actionscript guy but it's a classic problem - sort the two arrays in ascending order, then feed them into your third array, always selecting the lowest value from the two source arrays and escaping the write to the destination if what you would write is already at the end of the list - you'll end up with a sorted list of the unique values in the n input arrays

Comment: always selecting the lowest value from the two source arrays and escaping the write to the destination if what you would write is already at the end of the list - you'll end up with a sorted list of the unique values in the n input arrays?  Could not get this point. Can you give an example

Comment: sort the two arrays - then create a new empy array, then go into a while(either sorted array not empty) { find which sorted array has the lowest value, take it, and advance pointer for that array - if the value you selected isn't at the end of the array you are filling, add it to the end}

Answer (score 1):

For more properties, use something like:

```
function equals(o1:Object, o2:Object):Boolean
{
    if (o1 == o2) return true;
    if (!o1 || !o2) return false;

    for (var key:String in o1)
    {
        if (!(key in o2)) return false;
        if (o1[key] != o2[key]) return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```